# mysql using limit in a left join not working properly

Tags: mysql

I have two tables looking like this

**Patient** (table 1)

```
id |  name 
------------
1  | robel  
2  | dave
```

**Patient_followup** (table 2)

```
 id | Patient_id | date_created
 -----------------------
 1  | ---- 1  -- | 01/01/2015     
 2  | -----1  -- | 01/07/2016
```

I want to display all the patients with their perspective latest followup data. so i tried using this query

```
Select * from patient 
left join Patient_followup pf on pf.Patient_id = patient.id
order by pf.date_created
Limit 1
```

but this is giving me only the first patient robel. i tryed removing the limit and its giving me two records of robel and one record of dave because robel has two followup data. so what should i do to get only one record of each patient ?

Comment: It's working exactly as expected. `LIMIT 1` is applied to your query, which limits the output to exactly 1 record. To get one record per patient you'll need to use aggregation (`GROUP BY patient.id` etc).

Comment: There is only one patient.

Comment: yea group by will get me one record per patient , but the problem is i want to get the latest followup data also. I am sure my solution would have worked if all the patients had atleast one followup data.

Comment: I am sure it wouldn't

Comment: I had a working procedure with this exact kind of senario and its working . there iare two tables patient and patient_history and every patient had atleast one history and this worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select 
    * 
from 
    patient 
left join 
    (SELECT
        id as pf_id, 
        MAX(date_created) as latest_followup_date, 
        Patient_id
     FROM 
        Patient_followup 
     GROUP BY 
        Patient_id) as pf
ON pf.Patient_id = patient.id
```

Comment: I would say this looks close, however you just lost basically all the other data except date from the Patient follow-up table.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... The design for the Patient_followup table involves only patients_id which is a foreign key, its primary (id) and date_created.... wouldn't mind though adding the other values... edited my answer....

Answer (score 1):

1) "Limit 1" will only return the first result. Typically this is used if the query will result in a very large result set and you only want the first few results.

Ex:

```
"LIMIT 30" will show the first 30 rows of the query.
```

2) I would change to setup of the tables so the query is smoother. Right now, you create a new line for each follow-up date even if the patient is already created. You could add another column in the table named "FollowUpDate". That way each patient record has the table id, patient id, creation date and followup date in the same row. That way, each patient has only one row.

EX:

```
Patient (table 1)

id |  name  | created_date | next_followup_date |

 1 |  Robel |  01/01/2015  |     01/01/2016     |
 2 |  Dave  |[created_date]| [next_follup_date] |


Patient_followup (table 2)

id | Patient_id | date_created |  followUpDate  |

1 |       1     |  01/01/2015  |   06/01/2016   | // example date
2 |       1     |  01/01/2015  |   01/01/2016   |
3 |       2     |[date created]| [FollowUpDate] |
```

3) Change query to:

Use this select statement to get all patient records.

```
Select * from patient 
left join Patient_followup pf on pf.Patient_id = patient.id
order by pf.Patient_id
```

Use this select statement to get the specific patient record information.

```
Select * from patient 
inner join Patient_followup pf on pf.Patient_id = patient.id
where patient.id = 1 //to get robel. Edit this line as necessary, perhaps by user input...
order by pf.followUpDate
```

NOTE: When you insert a new record in Patient_followup, make sure you update Patient.next_followup_date.

I hope this helps!

Comment: The problem to ur solution is that i need to save all the records of the patient meaning a patient could come in more than once for followup and i should create a record everytime he comes in for followup.

Comment: okay. So are you looking to view one patient record that contains each followup date (as in the patients history) or are you looking to view all patients with their next followup date?

Comment: I've edited my answer to better reflect a solution you could try that would allow you to keep you followup date history in the Patient_followup table and the next followup date in the patient table. I also provided two example Select statements based off the type of info you might need to grab.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by **anton** in the first comment, you need to use aggregation to get one record per patient.

```
Select patient.*,MAX(pf.date_created) as followupdate,group_concat(pf.date_created) from patient 
 left join Patient_followup pf on pf.Patient_id = p.patient.id
group by patient.id
order by pf.date_created
```

Here, you will get your values comma separated.